# Relacionamentos JPA Spring Boot Rest Fetch Eager

Tags: java, web-service, spring, rest, spring-boot

Estou com uma aplicação que serve um rest service json (não é bem um rest, mas tudo bem). A aplicação utiliza Spring Boot para rodar, uso o PagingAndSortingRepository.

O problema é que ao servir uma entidade com relacionamento Muitos para um:

```
@Entity
public class City {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity=State.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="state_id")
    private State state;
```

Ele entrega assim:

```
"id" : 1,
"name" : "Cidade exemplo",
"capital" : true,
"_links" : {
    "self" : {
        "href" : "http://meu_dominio/rest/cities/1"
    },
    "city" : {
      "href" : "http://meu_dominio/rest/cities/1"
    },
    "state" : {
      "href" : "http://meu_dominio/rest/cities/1/state"
    }
}
```

Mas eu queria que fosse assim:

```
"id" : 1,
"name" : "Cidade exemplo",
"capital" : true,
"state" : {
    "id" : 1,
    "name" : "Estado Exemplo",
    "initials" : "EX",
    "_links" : {
        "self" : {
            "href" : "http://meu_dominio/rest/states/1"
         },
        "state" : {
            "href" : "http://meu_dominio/rest/states/1"
        }
    }
},
"_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://meu_dominio/rest/cities/1"
    },
    "city" : {
      "href" : "http://meu_dominio/rest/cities/1"
    }
}
```

Como configurar para que fique assim? Agradeço desde já.

---

Após deputar a minha aplicação pude perceber que a Entidade State é buscada corretamente, só não é exibida no JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver usando Projections. Assim:

import org.springframework.data.rest.core.config.Projection;

```
@Projection(name = "fullCity", types = { City.class })
public interface CityProjection {

    Long getId();
    String getName();
    boolean getCapital();
    State getState();

}
```

E no meu Repository:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(excerptProjection = CityProjection.class)
public interface Cities extends PagingAndSortingRepository<City, Long>{

}
```

Agradeço a todos que tentaram ajudar.